# Run trough one rgba to another based on percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say i have this both rgba codes:

**rgba(150, 160, 255, 1)** and **rgba(195, 0, 0, 1)**

I want to pass from one to another by a 0/100 percentage.

0% will be **rgba(150, 160, 255, 1)**

100% will be **rgba(195, 0, 0, 1)**

I'm trying to make a HeatMap with this.

How can i determinate what rgba will be at let say... 30%!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each value `x` in your code:

```
x = min_x + (max_x - min_x)*percentage/100
```

(Note: `max_x` can be smaller than `min_x`)

Comment: A princípio você é BR, então responderei em BR hehe ^^

Excelente código. Obrigado! Sucesso!

Answer (score 1):

For each component, you just have to do `start+(end-start)*percentage`

So for your 30% you'd have:

```
red = 150 + (195 - 150) * 0.3 = 205.5
green = 160 + (0 - 160) * 0.3 = 112
blue = 255 + (0 - 255) * 0.3 = 178.5
alpha = 1 + (1 - 1) * 0.3 = 1
```

Your final colour will therefore be `rgba(206, 112, 179, 1)`